# When try to log in as user : Target class [Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateSessionController] does not exist

Tags: authentication, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel 8, I am trying to make a multi auth system for admin and user.
I made a guard for admin, in FortifyServiceProvider in register method I added return Auth::guard('admin');

These are routes

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'admin', 'middleware'=>['admin:admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/login', [AdminController::class, 'loginForm']);
    Route::post('/login',[AdminController::class, 'storeAdmin'])->name('admin.login');
});



Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,admin', 'verified'])->get('/admin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');


Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,web', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

AdminController:

```
      <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline;
use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;

use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The guard implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;

    }

    public function loginForm(){
        return view('auth.login', ['guard' => 'admin']);
    }

    /**
     * Show the login view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse
     */
    public function create(Request $request): LoginViewResponse
    {
        return app(LoginViewResponse::class);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a new session.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function storeAdmin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
            return app(LoginResponse::class);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the authentication pipeline instance.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
     */
    protected function loginPipeline(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback, $request)
            ));
        }

        if (is_array(config('fortify.pipelines.login'))) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                config('fortify.pipelines.login')
            ));
        }

        return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter([
            config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
            Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication()) ? RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class : null,
            AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
            PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request): LogoutResponse
    {
        $this->guard->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return app(LogoutResponse::class);
    }
}
```

I can log in as an admin but got the error when try to log in as a user
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Because bootstrap cache is in `bootstrap/cache/routes_v7.php`.

***Solution:*** Remove cache

1. ```
   php artisan cache:clear
   ```
2. ```
   php artisan optimize
   ```
3. Reload.

DONE